# Simple curtain effect on hover using pure CSS

Tags: css, effect

I am trying to make a simple curtain effect. When we over the card (in this case, an image), to have a half-transparent layer coming from the top to the bottom of this image, within 1 second of transition. I already did it before and now I can't understand what I am missing. The code is pretty simple and should be working, I need a simple solution, any javascript or advanced technique is necessary.

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/jorgemonte/pen/rKvmpo

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<a class="card" href="">
<img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

CSS:

```
.card{
  display:inline-block;
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid black;
}

.image:before{
    content:"";
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    opacity:0;
    visibility:hidden;
    transform-origin:top center;
    transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
    transition:1s;
}

.card:hover .image:before{
    opacity:1;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS [pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) `::before` and `::after` can only exist on elements that are capable of having children. See this note from MDN:

> Note: The pseudo-elements generated by `::before` and `::after` are
>   contained by the element's formatting box, and thus don't apply to
>   replaced elements such as `<img>`, or to `<br>` elements.

Moving your `::before` to the `.card` div fixes this issue:

```css
.card {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.card::before {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transform-origin: top center;
  transform: scale3d(1, 0, 1);
  transition: 1s;
}

.card:hover::before {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<a class="card" href="">
  <img class="image" src="https://www.w3schools.com/w3images/fjords.jpg" alt="">
</a>
```

Comment: Clicked the top arrow and almost forgot the checkmark lol. Thanks man.